# Run-time linking to dynamic libraries not on LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, g++, shared-libraries

I'm trying to link a project of mine to a particular set of custom-compiled libraries placed on the project's base directory [proj_dir]/lib  - not on any of the system's /lib, /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib - to avoid conficts with the installed stock versions of those same libraries.

I'm able to compile the project by passing the library path with the `-L` flag, but I get `error while loading shared libraries libXXX.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when I run the compiled binary, and `ldd` tells me it can't find those particular libs.

On the other hand, I am able to run it without issue if I pass `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[proj_dir]/lib` to the executable. Still, is there a way to link those libraries implicitly, without having to manually set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime?

Comment: I think you are out of luck. If you did put the full path in, then what if someone can't put this extra dynlib at that exact path on their system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either

1. Write a wrapper script to always include `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before calling the actual program (more flexible).
2. Add `-Wl,-rpath=<directory>` to your linker options to add a directory to the runtime library search path. So assuming you have a `libfoo.so` and your program and DSO are located in the same directory, your compilation command could look like this: `gcc -o myprogam main.c -L. -lfoo -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'`.

*Update:* As correctly noted by Maxim, setting `-rpath=.` [is dangerous and should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158546/linux-c-trys-to-load-one-specific-library-using-an-absolute-path-while-all-ot/42159803#42159803).

For `-Wl,`, see the [gcc manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) and for `-rpath` see the [ld manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

Comment: @UKMonkey that only works if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `.`

Comment: @andreee This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Do not set `-rpath` to `.` - it is a security hole allowing easy hijacking of your application. Set it to `$ORIGIN`.